# Return selected values in a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox

I have in Access a single column table, Table1 with cell values 11-20.

I created a listbox on a form to multiselect cell values of this table.

[image: Listbox List38]

I need those selected values to filter a column in another table. I tried to retrieve the selected values as below but it did not help, especially `ItemData(oItem + 1)` returning only Null.

```
    Dim oItem As Variant
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iCount As Integer

    iCount = 0

    Debug.Print Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemsSelected.Count

    If Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then

        For Each oItem In Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemsSelected

            Debug.Print oItem

            If iCount = 0 Then
                sTemp = sTemp & Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemData(oItem + 1)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            Else
                sTemp = sTemp & "," & Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemData(oItem + 1)
                iCount = iCount + 1
            End If

            Debug.Print Forms.frmPassQuer2.List38.ItemData(oItem + 1)

        Next oItem

    Else
        MsgBox "Nothing was selected from the list", vbInformation
        Exit Sub  'Nothing was selected

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `oItem + 1` ? You need `.ItemData(oItem)`.

Comment: oItem+1=row number of the list@Andre

Comment: Just open the online help for `ItemsSelected` and look at the example, and you will see that `+ 1` is wrong.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea about retrieving selected values in a listbox?

Comment: I don't know how else to tell you. Use `.ItemData(oItem)`, following the online help example, or https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-itemsselected-property-access

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link helps. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/listbox-itemsselected-property-access

The key here is `forms.formName.ListName.column(column number,oItem)`. There are usually more than one columns in a listbox.  `column(column number,oItem)` locates the cell of which column and which row.